# Date is incrementing by a month after daylight saving is over in Javascript

Tags: javascript

im trying to add dates to an array, all works well, date is incremented by one but after the first of october the javascript increments it by a month.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var startDate = new Date();
 for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      currentDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + i);
console.log (currentDate);
    }
```

OUTPUT:

- Mon Sep 28 2015 11:58:23 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
- Tue Sep 29 2015 11:58:23 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
- Wed Sep 30 2015 11:58:23 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
- Thu Oct 01 2015 11:58:23 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
- Sun Nov 01 2015 11:58:23 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try with setTime() with adding number of days in milliseconds instead of setDate() to add days to a date.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var startDate = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
  currentDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + (i*86400000));
  console.log(currentDate);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with daylight savings, it has to do with what you are doing to currentDate

- i == 0. CurrentDate.setDate = 28 + 0 = 28, Date is 28/Sep
- i == 1. CurrentDate.setDate = 28 + 1 = 29, Date is 29/Sep
- i == 2. CurrentDate.setDate = 28 + 2 = 30, Date is 30/Sep
- i == 3. CurrentDate.setDate = 28 + 3 = 31, Date is 31/Sep, which becomes  01/Oct ... **NOTE now CurrentDate month is OCTOBER**
- i == 4. CurrentDate.setDate = 28 + 4 = 32, Date is 32/Oct, becomes 1st November

etc

You can achieve what you want without needing to worry about how many days in a month with this

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var startDate = new Date();
 for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1); // <<<===
      //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^             ^
      console.log (currentDate);
 }
```

Comment: I was going to try and explain this in my answer but couldn't think of a concise way to do it. +1 for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without startDate:

```
var currentDate = new Date();

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1); // Notice + 1 not + i
    console.log(currentDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured out the problem:

First you need to recognise what `setDate` actually does. It sets the day of the month. So lets iterate through the loop and keep track of the Date object:

```
currentDate => {d: 28, m: 9}
startDate => {d: 28, m: 9}
currentDate.setDate(28 + 1)
currentDate => {d: 29, m: 9}
currentDate.setDate(28 + 2)
currentDate => {d: 30, m: 9}
currentDate.setDate(29 + 3)
currentDate => {d: 1, m: 10} // month changed!!!
currentDate.setDate(29 + 4)
// month changed again since the old month
// is still 10, not 9
currentDate => {d: 1, m: 11}
```

Try using `setTime()` and `getTime()` or completely delegate date operations to a liblary like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)